# training convolutional neural network takes long time in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, training-data

I translated TensorFlow code to Pytorch code but it takes a long time.
It takes 6 hours to train in TensorFlow slim but it takes about 42 hours in PyTorch. (3200 epochs)

I use the profiler function to check the time each function takes.
But it says to (maybe `.to(device)`) function occupy a large portion of CPU time.

result of the profiler (5 epochs):

[image]

Below codes is a part of codes for training

```
with pf.profile() as prof :
    for epoch in range(5):

        # Print epoch
        print(f'Starting epoch {epoch+1}')

        # Set current loss value
        current_loss = 0.0
        tot_loss = 0.0
        
        # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # Get inputs
            inputs, targets = data
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            targets = targets.cuda()
            
            # Zero the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
                
            # Perform forward pass
            outputs = model(inputs)
                
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
                
            # Perform backward pass
            loss.backward()
            
            # Perform optimization
            optimizer.step()
                
            # Print statistics
            if i % 10000 == 9999:
                break
```

Comment: Are you using the same input dimensions, same batch size, the same model and training for the same amount of time?

Comment: Yes. I transform all data to make the size of data be [3,64,64]